# How to create a path for copy function in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, function

I have a problem with my COPY on sqlWorkbench.
I need to do a copy function from db TO a path that I create at the moment because is different for each table.
I have this error ' ERROR: syntax error at or near "||"'

I have created the path with the concat operator but i have the error at ||

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION copy_func(IN table_name text, IN days numeric) 
RETURNS void AS 
$body$ 
DECLARE    

BEGIN        

 COPY (SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE backup = 1) TO '/var/audiobays/logs/audit/' || table_name || '_deletions_(' || date-days|| ').csv' CSV DELIMITER ',' HEADER; 
END 
$body$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`COPY` can only take string literals for the path. If you need a dynamic path you can use dynamic SQL to build and execute the statement.

```
DECLARE    
  statement text;
BEGIN        
  statement := 'COPY (SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE backup = 1) TO ''/var/audiobays/logs/audit/' || table_name || '_deletions_(' || date-days|| ').csv'' CSV DELIMITER '','' HEADER;';
  EXCUTE statement;  
END;
```